# (index):36 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

index.html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="bg-dark">
        <div id="login-card" class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1>Wallpaper App Admin</h1>

                <form id="login-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-login">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <script>
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    window.location.href = "admin.html";
                } else {
                    // No user is signed in.
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

app.js code

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*******",
    authDomain: "******",
    databaseURL: "*****",
    projectId: "*****",
    storageBucket: "*****",
    messagingSenderId: "*****",
    appId: "*****",
    measurementId: "*****"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



    $("#btn-login").click(function(){

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password  = $("#password").val();

        var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        result.catch(function(error){
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = errror.message;

            console.log(errorCode);
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    });
```

Here I am using Firebase authentication sing-in-method as an Email/password. and in Firebase console I enable it. And already I saved one user in the firebase console. But I have an error like this, so my website doesn't work well.
This is the error

```
(index):36 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
    at (index):36
```

It shows this line as an error line, but I cannot understand why.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
```

Here I have some problems with this line. The code line is the same in firebase documentation but it doesn't work. I am using Visual Code as a tool for coding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `defer` from the script tag for the firebase-auth script.  That's causing it to be loaded only after it's required by your code.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Read about [defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp).

Comment: Great! On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and mark answers as correct using the buttons on the left if the answer was helpful.